# How to monitor c++ daemon process?

Tags: c++, linux, daemon

I develop one daemon tcp server with boost asio, I want to know is there any daemon manager lib to monitor the process, if the server process is dead, the manager can restart it

Comment: if you develop a daemon manager daemon, you will then need a daemon manager manager daemon to manage your daemon manager daemon.

Comment: runsv is probably what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use the very powerfull [daemontools](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html) to manage everything. These tools allow very in grained monitoring, restarting etc.

If you don't need this power the following shell-script is often enough:

```
while true; do
   $PROCESS
   sleep $SLEEP_TIME
done
```

This takes care of restarting your system when it crashes, but there is not much to it and if you need additions you will be out of luck.